# Boto Pagination for Kafka Topic

Tags: python, pagination, apache-kafka, boto

I'm learning Kafka on python. The source system sends the clickstream data  for minute into S3 bucket under prefixes created for every minute.I want to use boto Pagination on S3 to read the data continuously and send the data to Kafka Topic.
 This Kafka Topic will be read by another team to do some analytics.Ia my approach a good one.?

Thanks Jerome

Comment: Your approach probably isn't as scalable as putting the click events immediately onto Kafka, then sending the Kafka data to S3. In other words, how do you continously read "pages" in S3 without some "sleep interval". You're not doing streaming with this approach, it's batching based on the minute prefixes (which aren't necessarily guaranteed to be filled at the end of every minute)